# How to catch a default error as something?

Tags: python, try-catch

Then using try catch in python you can catch errors and assign them to a variable with the `as` keyword

```
try
  do something..
except IOError as e:
  do something with e..
```

However then trying to do the same thing without knowing the type of error python complains about the syntax.

```
try
  do something..
except as e:
  do something with e..
```

Is there any way to catch a default error and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is. All exceptions derive from the `Exception` class.

So you can do:

```
try:
    doSomething()
except Exception as e:
    doSomethingWithException(e)
```

It is a kind of catch-all line.

Comment: This may have been correct in 2012, but it's no longer true that all exceptions derive from the `Exception` class. They all derive from the `BaseException` class, with errors such as `GeneratorExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` not being `Exception`s. However, I agree this is still the correct answer, as you typically don't want to catch these - you want to be able to keyboard interrupt, for instance.   See https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy for the exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sys.exc_info().  This allows you to handle exceptions on Python 2.x and Python 3.x with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

The conventional manner is:

```python
try:
    do_whatever()
except Exception as e:
    handle_it()
```

Although it's ill-advised to catch such broad excepts - it's preferable to catch specific exceptions you know you can handle and let anything else propogate.

It's worth noting that KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit inherit from BaseException and not Exception, so these wouldn't be caught were you expecting to cater for those, but that shouldn't be a problem as they should be handled at the top level anyway.